# Is it better to add accept encoding gzip for HTTP request headers in android?

Tags: android, http-headers

Just wanted to know if it is better to have `"Accept-Encoding", "gzip"` in request headers while making HTTP request in android?

If not then in which cases it is not preferable? Also can it be used for requests returning XML or JSON as response?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gzip encoding is used to cut down the size of the data being transmitted over the netwrok. It compresses it into a zip and gives you a smaller compressed version which in turn reduces bandwidth usage and makes for faster programs. So i would say there is no harm in adding the `"gzip"` tag as it would definitely speed up the `get` process in most cases.  A good site you should probably look at:
[Is this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/)

And yes. It can be used with xml.

**Some of the issues are**

- Most of the images are already highly compressed and cant be
  compressed further.
- Some of the older versions have problems with compression but this
  should not be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer so what i could conclude here is that it is more of server side handling which has to be done before the android apps can send the request or parse the response. Correct me if i am wrong!